# Loading jQuery: Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Whenever I try to load the latest version of jQuery into my website I get this error in the google chrome console;

```
Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

I think its weird since all I am doing is loading.

```
<head>
    <title>Home</title>

    <link href = "style.css" rel = "stylesheet">
    <link rel = "shortcut icon" href = "\images\design\logo.ico" type = "image/x-icon"/>

    <script src = "\script\messageSender.js"> </script>
    <script src = "\script\currentTime.js"> </script>

    <script src = "\libraries\jQuery.js"> </script>

    <div class = "header" id = "header">
        <a href = "/">
            <img src = "\images\design\header.png" alt = "Header" width = "467" height = "113" title = "Home">
        <a>
    </div>

    <div class = "menu">
        <a href = "/">Home</a>
        <a href = "/about.html">About</a>
        <a href = "/software.html">Software</a>
        <a href = "/mods.html">Mods</a>
        <a href = "/contact.html">Contact</a>
    </div>
</head>
```

messageSender class

```
function userAlert(Message){
alert(Message);}
```

currentTime class

```
function getYear() {
    Date = new Date
    Year = Date.getYear()

    var Copy = '&copy;';

    if (Year < 1900) {
        Year = Year + 1900
        document.write(Copy + " " + Year + " " + "Trevi Awater")
    } else {
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to place jQuery.js before other scripts

Comment: show us your javascript

Comment: turns out removing the currentTime.js from there solves the problem, any ideas why?

Comment: Looks like you're missing several semicolons in that file. I count 3 required and 4 total.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect this could have happened (but without knowing the usages of those classes I can't be sure this is the actual fault), since because you stated those js files as classes.

```
var x = new getYear(); // x is an object

// when trying to call the object as function
x(); // Uncaught TypeError: object is not a function
```

Answer (score 0):

getYear() is deprecated, try getFullYear() instead.

Answer (score 0):

change the stack order of script inclusion:

```
<script src = "\libraries\jQuery.js"> </script>
<script src = "\script\messageSender.js"> </script>
<script src = "\script\currentTime.js"> </script>
```